# How to remove a PPA from CLI?

Tags: apt, ppa

So you want to try an app that is in a PPA, so you add the PPA like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository [some PPA]
```

Then you decided you don't like it or it's buggy or whatnot. 
What is the command to remove one?

Comment: Very complex answers to a simple question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Terminal/CLI run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove [some PPA]
```

Where `some PPA` is the repository that you wish to remove.

Don't forget to use `sudo apt update` after removing the PPA.

Comment: Try adding more information to your answer, so it will be more helpful to the other peoples.

Comment: @Ravexina threw in some filler words, other than defining `some PPA` the command is pretty self explanatory

Comment: Seems pretty self explanatory to me as well.

Comment: Your answer is right into the point and thank you for your edit.

Comment: How do I get the repository name?

Answer (score -2):

Please open up the Software and Updates menu and go to the *Other Software* tab. From there you can delete and add any PPA you like manually. You can also use Geany to quickly delete or drag and drop sources into your /etc/apt/sources.list  file.

Comment: @Emandudeguy the question specifically states they are looking from a solution from the CLI. If they are running Ubuntu server, they don't have GUI...

Comment: @CelticWarrior comments are not for the quality of an answer.  You vote up or down for that.  Comments are only to extract more detail.  Remember to play nice.

Comment: @Emandudeguy being offensive is not acceptable. Please dont do that again.